# Animation without affecting idle state

Tags: mapbox, react-map-gl

Currently, I have a animated circle that worked like this

```
const pulse = (map: MapRef, options: PulseOptions, step: number) => {
    const { widthKey, key, minWidth, maxWidth, sizePerStep, layerId } = options
    map.getMap().setPaintProperty(layerId, widthKey, [
        "interpolate",
        ["linear"],
        key,
        0,
        minWidth,
        1,
        getPulseWidth(minWidth, maxWidth, step, sizePerStep),
    ])
}

export const startPulse = async (mapRef: MapRef, options: PulseOptions) => {
    await mapRef?.getMap().once("idle")
    let step = options.step

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (step === options.steps) step = 0
        step += 1
        pulse(mapRef, options, step)
    }, options.ms)
}
```

By calling `setPaintProperty` in every n ms to achieve a pulsing effect, however, this will lead to the map will never go idle when doing `.once("idle")`

I tried [the mapbox tutorial one](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image-animated/), but the performance wan't great when having many markers, but looks like `triggerRepaint` will not affect the idle state.

Any idea on how can I implement `triggerRepaint` or any ways to not affect the idle state when `setPaintProperty`?